# Require JS some dependencies are not found and error as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've been using RequireJS for a little bit now but I'm still struggling to get to grips with it...

I have a simple project that has a number of JS plug-ins, as per my understanding I'm pulling these in via the `paths` object, but sometimes, when I add a new one and run my script, I get a console error explaining a dependency is `undefined`.

Here is my JS:

```
require.config({
  "paths": {
    "jquery": "/content/themes/my-theme/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
    "foundation": "/content/themes/my-theme/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min",
    "slick": "/content/themes/my-theme/bower_components/slick.js/slick/slick.min",
    "scrollmagic": "/content/themes/my-theme/bower_components/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/ScrollMagic.min"
  },
  "shim": {
    "foundation": ["jquery"],
    "slick": ["jquery"]
  }
});

require(['jquery', "foundation", "slick", "scrollmagic"], function($) {

  /* --------------------
      Variables
  ---------------------*/
  var 
    bodyEl      = $( 'body' ),
    isOpen      = false,
    content     = $( '.content' ),
    openbtn     = $( '#open-button' ),
    closebtn    = $( '#close-button' ),
    controller  = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  $(document).foundation();

  $(document).ready(function() {

    navInit();

    $('.main-slider').slick({
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 4000
    });
  });
});
```

I had my project running fine up until I added the latest dependency `scrollMagic`... when running in the browser I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Controller' of undefined`

I thought about adding this to the `shim` but as the plug-in isn't specifically dependant on anything (yet), it should be necessary.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you added $ for jQuery, you need to add parameters for the other modules you pass in

```
require(['jquery', "foundation", "slick", "scrollmagic"], function($, foundation, slick, ScrollMagic) {
```

This will work **assuming these are AMD compatible modules**.

If not, you'll need to shim them and add an exports assigning the library variable to the exports property. Here is an example from http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

```
shim: {
    'backbone': {
        //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
        //module value.
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
```

Comment: Ah so I've been misunderstanding what `shim` does then... it's not for dependencies per-se? Just the above code worked fine before I added `scrollmagic`.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a simple way to check whether my modules are AMD compatible? Or is it that the approach that you mentioned will just work?

Comment: From the documentation - shim: Configure the dependencies, exports, and custom initialization for **older, traditional "browser globals" scripts** that do not use define() to declare the dependencies and set a module value.



You should be able to check if your scripts export modules by checking the library documentation (or just google for requires + that library). Or you could just search the code for module.exports or amd. Or you could just what's in the answer and check if the parameter passed in has a value :-)